# Interior points of a convex set

Tags: general-topology, convex-analysis

If it is known that point I is an interior point of convex set C, would I be right in claiming that any point of the form K = pI + (1-p)X, where X is any other point in the convex set, p>0 and p<=1, is also an interior point?

Alternatively: a boundary point cannot be expressed as a convex combination of points where there is a non-trivial contribution from interior points.

Intuitively this seems to be the case, but I'm unable to prove it.

Comment: I believe this statement is also known as the line segment principle. See Theorem 6.1 of the following book. 
R. T. Rockafellar,Convex Analysis, vol. 28 of Princeton MathematicalSeries, Princeton University Press, Princeton, NJ, 1970.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since $I \in {\rm Int\,} C$, it has an open neighborhood $O$ lies completely inside $C$.

For any $K = pI + (1-p)X$ with $p \in (0,1]$, consider the map

$$\phi_p : y \mapsto X + \frac1p (y - X)$$

This map is continuous and send $K$ to $I$. The preimage $\phi^{-1}_p(O)$ will 
be open and contains $K$. For any $y \in \phi^{-1}_p(O)$, we have
$$x = \phi_p(y) \in O \subset C \quad\implies\quad y = px + (1-p) X \in C$$
because $C$ is convex. This implies $\phi^{-1}_p(O) \subset C$.
This means $K$ has an open neighborhood $\phi^{-1}_p(O)$ which lies completely inside $C$. i.e. $K \in {\rm Int\,}C$.

This argument works for any real topological vector space.

Comment: Why specifically real? Would it work for spaces with complex fields?

Comment: @MahathiVempati It will work. a complex TVS is automatically a real TVS.